# Отмена роута Angular UI-Router

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angular-ui-router

Как отменить слежение роута в Angular UI-Router?

У меня есть роут:

```
.state('article', {
      url: '/:url',
      templateUrl: '/templates/article.html',
      controller: BlogController,
      resolve: {
        acticlesProvider: acticlesProvider
      }
    })
```

Хочу, чтобы при роуте `/admin`, Angular не перехватывал, а шел обычный запрос.

Comment: что значит _обычный запрос_?

Comment: Его не перехватывал angular, тк когда пищу /admin он применяет роут /:url, а я хочу чтобы шел обычно запрос

Comment: вы используете html5mode?

Comment: да
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });

Answer (score 1):

Надо убрать поддержку html5, чтобы ссылки начинались с решетки, тогда он не будет конфликтовать.